# Probability calculation from Normal Distribution

Tags: probability, statistics, normal-distribution

Assume that we want to perform a one-sample t-test with null hypothesis $\mathbb{E}X=0$ and an alternative $\mathbb{E}X > 0$. We have an i.i.d. sample $x=(x_1, \ldots, x_{n})$ from X. Let n=100. To simplify calculations, let us assume that we have a large enough sample to reliably estimate the variance of X from the data and apply the central limit theorem. In other words, we will assume that sample mean $\bar{x}$ is distributed under normal law with expected value \mathbb{E}X and variance that is equal to $\mathrm{\mathop{Var}}_{+}(x)/n$, where $\mathrm{\mathop{Var}}_{+}(x)$ is unbiased sample variance of x. Assume that $\mathrm{\mathop{Var}}_{+}(x)=5$.

Find value $x_{crit}$​ such that probability to observe $\bar{x}\ge x_{crit}$​ is equal to 0.05. (Use scipy.stats.norm.ppf.).

Solution:

$P(\bar{x} \ge x_{crit}) = P(N(0,5/100) > Xcrit = 0.05\\P(Z > \frac{x_{crit}}{5/10})\\where Z \sim N(0,1)$

$\frac{x_{crit}}{5/10} = 1.645 ~~(using~ scipy.stats.norm.ppf(0.95)$

$x_{crit} = 1.645 \times \frac{5}{10} = 0.3678 \approx 0.37$

Assume that correct $\mathbb{E}X=0.5$. Find probability to observe $\bar{x} < x_{crit}$​ in this case. (Use $x_{crit}$​ found previously. Take into account the correct distribution of $\bar{x}$.)

What I used is as follows:
I created a Normal distribution with $\mathbb{E}X=0.5$ and $\sigma^2 = 5/100$ and then calculated the cumulative probability distribution to calculate the required probability.

$probability = scipy.stats.norm(0.5, 5/100).cdf(0.37) \approx 0.004$

But, as you may see it is extremely small for such a large region. May someone please suggest a correction?

Comment: I have by mistake written 5/10 but it is sqrt(5)/10.

Answer (score 1):

I was using the wrong sigma.

$sigma = \sqrt{5} / 10$

Using the value I got the $probability \approx 0.28$.

For the same I used:

$scipy.stats.norm(loc=0.5, scale=numpy.sqrt(5)/10).cdf(0.37) \approx 0.28$